# Hide the original file (paperclip)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Makes loading custom images, after downloading put a watermark. Paperclip by default puts the files in a folder called styles, such as original, thumb, medium, etc.
I want to hide the original file that is uploaded without a watermark, and leave the original size is available but only with a watermark.

Remove loadable file is not an option, they are needed for the archive.

I want a file kept in the same place and at the same time was not available unauthorized user? For example, a site administrator could view these files, and users could not.

Can cancan restrict access if someone will turn to the original file, the direct link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use

```
Paperclip.interpolates :maybe_public do |attachment, style|
  style == :original ? "private" : "public"
end

has_attached_file :image, :path => ":rails_root/:maybe_public/..."
```

And it's worked

Answer (score 1):

**try but I'm not sure**

```
has_attached_file :avatar, {
    :url => "/system/:hash.:extension",
    :hash_secret => "longSecretString"
}
```

Comment: See my solution, I found it. Thank you.